# Chrome has different source HTML than Internet Explorer?

Tags: python

[image]

When looking at reviews under source I get different results based on which browser I'm using.

Chrome:

[image]

Internet Explorer:

[image]
[image]

Using Python w/ requests and User-Agent for either Internet Explorer or Chrome gives me the same result as Internet Explorer:

```
>>> parse_google('https://play.google.com/store/movies/details?id=s8dGvpxGuCs')
ds: 11 ; data: [[[1, None, False], [[None, [[600], None, [604800]]]]]]
>>> parse_google('https://play.google.com/store/movies/details?id=s8dGvpxGuCs')
ds: 10 ; data: [[None, None, None, None, [False], [[None, [[600], None, [604800]]]], [[u'4.7', 4.67492], [None, [u'41', 41], [u'19', 19], [u'36', 36], [u'114', 114], [u'1,042', 1042]], [u'1,252', 1252], [u'505', 505]]], [3, 1, 3, 10, 100]]
```

You can verify this yourself with the following code (Chrome User-Agent):

```
>>> import json
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('https://play.google.com/store/movies/details?id=s8dGvpxGuCs', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36'})
>>> s = json.loads(response.content.split('AF_initDataCallback({key: \'ds:11\'')[1].split('data:function(){return ')[1].split('}});')[0])
>>> print s
[[[1, None, False], [[None, [[600], None, [604800]]]]]]
```

P.S.

I have noticed this for Microsoft's store as well, where Chrome shows div tags and Internet Explorer shows section tags.

Comment: it could be some html code generate via javascript that is not executed on internet explorer or the server returning browser customized code

Answer (score -1):

Oldskool Internet Explorer is not compatible with some modern HTML5 niceties, like, amongh others, `<section>` tags.

As a result, sites that want to support older browsers may generate old style HTML plus a few JS polyfills If they detect a legacy browser.